# reading string twice? What's the prob? C

Tags: c, string, function, scanf

In my code I have a menu with 4 options :

1-> am trying to read 2 strings, and then

2-> count the 'e'-s in them,

3-> quit the program, or

4-> print the two strings.

```
int add(char *str1, char *str2){
    int res=0;
    int index=0;
    for(index=0;index<20;index++){
        if( str1[index] == 'e'){
            res++;
        }
        if( str2[index] == 'e'){
            res++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
void fill(char *str1){
    scanf("%[^\n]s", str1);
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char c='A';
    int opt=0;
    char s1[20]="The first string";
    char s2[20]="The second string";

    printf(""
           "1. Set Strings\n"
           "2. calc\n"
           "3. ESC\n"
           "");

    while(c!=27){
        scanf("%d", &opt);
        switch(opt){
            case 1:
                fill(s1);
                fill(s2);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("sumOf'e'=%d\n",add(s1,s2));
                break;
            case 3:
                c=27;
                break;
            default:
                printf("%s, %s", s1, s2);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem Is with the reading:

The output:

> ```
>    1. Set Strings
>     2. calc
>     3. ESC
>     1
>     hey hey
>     hey hey hey
>     4
>     hey hey hey, The second string
> ```

so the problem is that it reads only into the first string. 
Can someone solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for this. Read the line with `fgets` and the parse it with `sscanf`.

Comment: Why does every newbie put `s` after `%[^\n]`?

Comment: btw, don't hardcode the length of the buffers, that breaks very easily. If `str1` and `str2` are strings, then use `strlen` for the length calculation. In the way you are doing, you might end up reading more 'e's than you should

Comment: 1) Code is having trouble with input yet code does not check the return value of `scanf()`.  Tip: Easier to solve many coding issues if code checks that return value.  2) `'\n'`is not  consumed as needed.

Comment: Why does every newbie use scanf?

Comment: @WilliamPursell cause he is newbie.

Comment: Because most every newbie is taught to do so.

Comment: If any teacher here, please stop teaching JUST scanf(), tell its consequences and its alternatives too AT THE SAME TIME. If you don't know, STOP TEACHING AND LEARN FIRST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `scanf` is that it behaves in a different way as people generally assume it does. `scanf` is a "scan formatted input" function, it works well when the input has a regular format. For random input, `scanf` is not the best choice. Take a look at this: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

How to use `fgets`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void cut_nl(char *str)
{
    if(str == NULL)
        return;

    int idx = strlen(str);

    if(str[idx-1] == '\n')
        str[idx-1] = 0;
}

int add(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    if(str1 == NULL)
        str1 = "";

    if(str2 == NULL)
        str2 = "";

    int counter = 0;
    int i;

    int len1 = strlen(str1);
    int len2 = strlen(str2);

    for(i = 0; i < len1; ++i)
        if(str1[i] == 'e')
            counter++;

    for(i = 0; i < len2; ++i)
        if(str2[i] == 'e')
            counter++;

    return counter;
}

int main(void)
{
    // for simplicity's sake, let's assume that the user
    // doesn't input more then 1023 characters
    char line1[1024], line2[1024];


    // here you should check if fgets returns NULL
    fgets(line1, sizeof line1, stdin);
    fgets(line2, sizeof line2, stdin);

    cut_nl(line1);
    cut_nl(line2);

    printf("sumOf 'e': %d\n", add(line1, line2));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. uses the proper signature for `main()` when the parameters will not be used
2. properly checks each call to `scanf()` to assure the call was successful
3. properly includes the needed header files
4. when checking the strings for occurrences of 'e' stops checking for each string when the end of the string is reached.
5. uses an appropriate error message when the user enters an invalid selection for the menu.
6. properly sizes the max characters the user can enter for each input string
7. caveat does not bother to check if the user entered a 'too long' input string, you should correct that by flushing the input buffer as needed.
8. properly declares each string holder to contain 19 characters plus the string terminator.
9. properly re-displays the menu when ever wanting the user to make a menu selection
10. properly prompts for each input from the user.
11. for ease of readability and understanding, separates code blocks via a single blank line, separates functions via two blank lines.
12. comments why each header file is being included.
13. the proposed code cleanly compiles.
14. note: the user entered strings cannot be on the same line, separated by a space, as each string only stops inputting as either 19 characters or when a newline '\n' is encountered

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf(), scanf()
#include <stdlib.h> // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h> // strlen()


// prototypes
int add(char *str1, char *str2);
void fill(char *str1);


int add(char *str1, char *str2)
{
    int res=0;

    for( size_t index=0; index < strlen( str1 ); index++ )
    {
        if( str1[index] == 'e')
        {
            res++;
        }
    }

    for( size_t index=0; index < strlen( str2 ); index++ )
    {
        if( str2[index] == 'e')
        {
            res++;
        }
    }

    return res;
} // end of function: add


void fill(char *currentStr)
{
    if ( 1 != scanf(" %19[^\n]", currentStr) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for string failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
} // end of function: fill


int main( void )
{
    char c='A';
    int opt=0;
    char s1[20]="";
    char s2[20]="";



    while(c!=27)  // not 'esc' key
    {
        printf(""
           "1. Set Strings\n"
           "2. calc\n"
           "3. quit\n");

        if( 1 != scanf("%d", &opt) )
        {
            perror( "scanf for menu option failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        switch(opt)
        {
            case 1:
                printf( "Enter first string, max 19 chars: " );
                fill(s1);
                printf( "Enter second string, max 19 chars: " );
                fill(s2);
                break;

            case 2:
                printf("sumOf 'e'= %d\n",add(s1,s2));
                break;

            case 3:
                c=27;
                break;

            default:
                printf(" %d is an invalid selection\n", opt);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```